# Projecting a point from a diameter to the circumference of a circle.

Tags: circles

What I want to know is if I have a unit circle centered at the origin with a diameter drawn along the y axis and I know the distance that a point on the diameter has from the center what would be the x coordinates of the points on the circumference with the same y coordinates. further more how would you repeat this process on bigger or smaller circles.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. You want to find the coordinates of points that have the same y-coordinate and lie on the circumference of the unit circle?

Comment: Yes that is my question.

Answer (score 1):

Say the circle with radius $r$ has equation $$x^2+y^2 =r^2 $$ and the point you have is $P(0,a)$ ($a$ is the distance of the point from the center) where $-r\le a\le r$. Then you want to solve for the intersection point of $y=a$ with the circle: $$x^2+a^2 =r^2 \implies x=\pm\sqrt{r^2-a^2}$$

Comment: best to write $|a|\le r$.

Comment: @Jamāl Yup. ${}$

Comment: also i think the OP is asking for the points that have the same y-coordinate as the point $P$ on the diameter along the y-axis.

Comment: @Jamāl And that is what I have provided.

Comment: shouldn't $P$ be of the form $(0,a)$ in that case?

Comment: @Jamāl Ahh yes nice catch

Comment: shouldn't it be y =

Comment: @AwardMathpu What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can solve this using trigonometry.

Let's say the point along the diameter (diameter being twice the radius, $r$) above the origin is $y$, $(0,y)$.
The angle the swept radius makes from the horizontal axis so that the $y$ component of the triangle is,$$y=r\cdot \sin(\theta)$$The points of this triangle being: $(0,0), (x,0),$ and $(x,y)$.

We can solve for $\theta$ using $$\theta = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)$$
Then, we can solve for the x-component using$$x=r\cdot \cos(\theta)$$
or,$$x=\frac{y}{\tan(\theta)}$$
Since you want both sides of the x-axis, the xs you are looking for are $\pm x$ of the above.